# Handle onClick() and onTouch() Both,android

Tags: android

I have perform onClick() and onTouch() on same imageView, simple open Gallery on onClick(),but problem is that my onclick() not work,while onTouch() work properly. can anyone clear me what was actual problem.Thank you. Here is my code..,

```
boolean isMoved=true;
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix=new Matrix();
    PointF startPoint=new PointF();
    PointF midPoint=new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    int NONE = 0;
    int DRAG = 1;
    int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            matrix.set(imageView.getImageMatrix());
            isMoved = false;
            startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            mode = DRAG;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!isMoved) {
                v.performClick();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x, event.getY()
                        - startPoint.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {

                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
                }
            }
            isMoved = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            oldDist = spacing(event);

            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(midPoint, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                isMoved = false;
            }
            break;
        }

        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }
@SuppressLint("FloatMath")
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to make the ImageView both clickable and moveable by touch.  If that is so, then I suggest looking into SimpleGestureDetector.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `onClick()` and `onTouch()` are GesturesDetectors and there is a system of consumption. Each time you make a Gesture on the tactile of the device, all the GesturesDetectors (`onClick()`, `onTouch()`, `onDoubleTap()`...) attached to this specific view will be called one by one. If at then end of the GestureDetector you return true, then the event is consummed and the others GestureDetector will not be call. If you return false, the event is not consummed and the next GestureDetector is called.

So in order to perform `onClick()` wich is called after `onTouch()` be sure to return false at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You havent given your onclick code so i assume that will be ok.
*You are returning **true** from ontouch return **false** there it will work*
When you return true then onClick method not execute if you want to execute onclick also then you have to return false from ontouch.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following logic to distinguish between `onTouch()` and `onClick()`

Declare:

```
private static final int DurationOfClick = 2000;  //duration of tap on screen
private long clickTime;
```

Now in `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` write the condition..

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            clickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            long duration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - clickTime;
            if(duration < DurationOfClick) {
                //click event has occurred write ur code
            }else{
                //touch event has occurred write ur code
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thnik code below wil be helpful for you ,try this

```
  ImageView image_name = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); //Find your image here
    image_name.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("test", "ontouch");
            return false;
        }
    });
    image_name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("test", "onclick");
        }

    });
```

or you can use **GestureDetector** property of android go through [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using GestureDetector and my issue solve. Thank you for suggestions here is my answer..,

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            v.performClick();
        } else {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                matrix.set(imageView.getImageMatrix());
                // isMoved = false;
                startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                /*
                 * if (!isMoved) { v.performClick(); }
                 */
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
                            event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {

                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
                    }
                }
                // isMoved = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                oldDist = spacing(event);

                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(midPoint, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    // isMoved = false;
                }
                break;
            }

            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```